# wifi and bluetooth not working when booting to another kernel

Tags: wireless, kernel, bluetooth

I am using HP-laptop-15q-byoxx with WiFi radio RTL8723DE.I have installed drivers for both WIFI and bluetooth  "dkms install" by google searching and going through askubuntu posts,both are working on kernel 4.15.0-23 but when I boot Ubuntu on a previous kernel 4.15.0-20 both WIFI and bluetooth stopped working.Do I have to install drivers again for each kernel update in future updates.I have installed Ubuntu 18.04.

dkms status

```
btrtl-rtl8723de, 0.1~bionic, 4.15.0-23-generic, x86_64: installed
rtlwifi-new, 0.6, 4.15.0-23-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: Please post output of `dkms status` to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 edited with dkms status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dkms` doesn't build "backwards" with default config.

If you install a new kernel, it will build the driver for it, but it doesn't do it for old ones that were installed before you installed the dkms package.

Boot with the `4.15.0-20` and install the driver for it this way:

```
sudo dkms install btrtl-rtl8723de/0.1~bionic
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
sudo update-initramfs -uk $(uname -r)
```

You don't need to reinstall packages, just neet to build the modules. And you don't need an internet connection for it.

You can try `--all` option to build for all installed kernels, but I didn't test it on install, only on remove. E.g:

```
sudo dkms install btrtl-rtl8723de/0.1~bionic  -all
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6 --all
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

This way it is supposed to build for all installed kernels, but as mentioned above it is not guaranteed to work.